# what is difference here between Partial View & View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know the difference between View and PartialView, but Is there any difference here in below code (as both return the view with expected result),

**1.**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**2.**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you specified Layout property inside your content view there is no difference. When returning `View()`, ViewStart.cshtml executed but when returning `PartialView()`, ViewStart.cshtml was not executed.So when view does not set Layout property, `return View()` can take Layout from Viewstart.cshtml but return PartialView() cannot.For more information [Rendering difference between PartialView() and view()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32025301/4293929)

If your content.cshtml contains this code block they are same and generate view wrapped in specified layout.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

If Content view does not specify any Layout, `return View()` gets its Layout property from ViewStart.cshtml and generates a view wrapped in layout. But `return PartialView()` only generates the content view because Viewstart.cshtml is not executed when you `return PartialView()`.

Comment: @user584018 you should read answer in the link for more clarification

Answer (score 0):

View will return layout with view content.
Partial returns only content