# ASP.NET MVC Razor Sections and Partials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, sections, renderpartial

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET MVC and Razor.  We've been modifying and developing based on existing code.  Thus, there is a lot of duplication (ugh!).  So I started looking at Partial pages and learning about Sections.  I followed these tutorials but I'm still a bit confused.

[ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts and Sections with Razor](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor)

[Various ways of using Shared Layout in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/996879/Various-ways-of-using-Shared-Layout-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

[Optional Razor Sections with Default Content](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/08/optional-razor-sections-with-default-content.aspx)

[Razor, Nested Layouts and Redefined Sections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/15/razor-nested-layouts-and-redefined-sections.aspx)

I've been able to create Sections with Partials in them.  My question is:

**While one section will always change upon user selection, I may not want to blow away the content section.  I may just want to add a new tab based on the Sub Menu item selected by the user.**

The plan is to have a **_Layout** that contains the **_Header** and a **Section** for the **SideBar** (Sub Menu).  Based on the user's selection in the **_Header**, the Sub Menu list of options will change in the **SideBar** and the **Content** will be a container that can contain a **Grid** when the Home button is selected, or it can contain a **Tabbed** view for the other buttons.

[image]

## The Problem

Let's say the user selects **Billing** from the **_Header** and then selects two items from the **Sub Menu** on the left; in the Content section, two tabs should display (one for each item selected in the Sub Menu).  Then, if the user selects **Reports** from the **_Header**, the **SideBar** should changed to display the appropriate **Sub Menu** items for **Reports** but I do not want the two tabs for **Billing** to be blown away.  Instead, I want to add additional tabs for each item the user selected from the **Reports** Sub Menu.

---

**Below is the code from the demo, which shows how I put the Partial page code in the Sections.  Obviously I'm still confused over the approach that I should take to accomplish the layout I need.**

---

## _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")

</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <h1>My Site Header</h1>
    </div>

    @if (IsSectionDefined("SideBar"))
    {
        <div id="sidebar">
            @RenderSection("SideBar")
        </div>
    }

    <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>Site Footer - &copy; Santa Clause</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

## Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@Html.Partial("HomeContentPartial")

@section SideBar {

    @Html.Partial("HomeMenuPartial")

}
```

## .CSS

```
#header {
    background-color: #5c87b2;
    color: white;
    padding: 1px; }

#content {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px; }

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: dotted 5px red;
    width: 180px; }

#footer {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both; }
```

## HomeMenuPartial.cshtml

```
<p>This sidebar has "Home Page" specific content.</p>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
</ul>

<p>The time is: @DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()</p>
```

## HomeContentPartial.cshtml

```
<h2>Welcome to my Site</h2>

<p>This is our home page.</p>

<p>Not super exciting is it?</p>

<p>Yada, Yada, Yada.</p>
```